# DS160 information change

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

My ex submitted the DS 160 for me while we were married but didn't book the visa appointment/paid mrv fees. Now 4 years later I want to visit US on tourist visa and am trying to submit Ds160 mentioning my status as "single".

Will it cause any issues due to the fact that in the old ds160 my status was "married"?

Thanks.

Comment: You were married then, but you're single now, correct? If so, I'm not understanding why you think there would be an issue; the information was accurate at the time it was provided. Or am I misunderstanding something about the situation?

Comment: Currently my divorce proceedings are going on. My final hearing is in September. And i want to get my us visa before that so filled the ds160 as single.

Comment: I would like to know if the DS160 once submitted the information is retained in the system and verified if a new DS160 is filled years later with change in particulars.

Answer (score 2):

Until your divorce is final, you must continue to select "Married".

Some countries have a concept of legal separation, a status which precedes divorce. You may be separated in fact, but the courts in India do not recognize the concept of legal separation. You should not select the "Legally Separated" option if the web site shows it to you.